# What exactly does DAC do? (Data - tier Applications)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010, dac

So I'm trying to figure out the purpose of DAC, so I tried reading [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633713(v=sql.105).aspx); But I am very overwhelmed by the definition (Since technically, I'm still a newbie anyway) Could anyone explain it to me in a very simple manner? based from my understanding, its something used in 3 tier programming. another question would be, could DAC be used like DTS in SQL SERVER 2000?

EDIT: I'm trying to learn DAC through google searches, but I still don't get why this feature is not used, and why even use it

Comment: "A DAC defines the instance level objects, schemas, and database objects used by a three-tier or client-server application"

Comment: @MitchWheat what's the difference between creating objects in SQL SERVER and DAC?

Comment: I'm still so intrigued by how they picked "DAC" to the be the acronym for "Data-tier Application".  Surely "DTA" or "DAP" would have made much more sense.

Comment: Whatever the acronym is, I'm still unaware of its use. I would love to learn more about DAC.

Comment: I always thought DAC stands for "Data Access Component": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692877(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm pertaining to this DAC

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633713(v=sql.105).aspx